# How to interpret rank bar plot of a MCMC trace?

Tags: bayesian, pymc, ranks, probabilistic-programming, traceplots

I am learning how to use PyMC for Bayesian inference. I coded up a random intercept $Y = \gamma + \sum_{j=1}^3 \beta_j \mathbb{I}_j + \epsilon$ and looked at the trace plots. Here is a `graphviz` visualization of the model's structure.

[image]

Out of curiosity I tried `kind="rank_bars"` in `arviz.plot_trace`. Here is the output.

[image]

And here is a closer look at the beta params' rank bar plot.

[image]

What diagnostic information about the MCMC simulation do these plots tell me about the simulation? What would it look like if something was working/not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the dox](https://python.arviz.org/en/stable/api/generated/arviz.plot_rank.html#arviz.plot_rank):

> From the paper: Rank plots are histograms of the ranked posterior
> draws (ranked over all chains) plotted separately for each chain. If
> all of the chains are targeting the same posterior, we expect the
> ranks in each chain to be uniform, whereas if one chain has a
> different location or scale parameter, this will be reflected in the
> deviation from uniformity. If rank plots of all chains look similar,
> this indicates good mixing of the chains.
>
> This plot was introduced by Aki Vehtari, Andrew Gelman, Daniel
> Simpson, Bob Carpenter, Paul-Christian Burkner (2019):
> Rank-normalization, folding, and localization: An improved R-hat for
> assessing convergence of MCMC. arXiv preprint
> https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08008